# How to show phpinfo() only in a new tab?

Tags: php, plugin-development

My problem is that I want to add a link to my plugin which should direct the admin user to a new blank page which shows phpinfo()?
Can anyone direct me how to do this? I know WordFence has a feature like that under their Diagnosis page, I want my plugin to basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying the info in the front-end, hook into `wp` or `init`, otherwise `init` or `admin_init` will work on admin:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
    if( current_user_can("manage_options") && ! is_feed() && isset( $_GET["my_plugin_show_phpinfo"] ) ) {
        ?>

            <!-- Output things -->

            <?php phpinfo(); ?>

        <?php
        exit;
    }
});
```

Now if you go to `http://example.com/?my_plugin_show_phpinfo=1` it will display your custom content only. Hope that helps.

Edit: Added conditional to limit the tab for admins only. Thanks TomC!

Comment: Possibly should add `&& is_admin()` to that if statement.

Comment: Yes @TomC but I think OP wants to show them on front-end.. It's been a while since I used WordFence..

Comment: Oh yes - I meant `&& current_user_can('administrator')`

Comment: Right!! I will edit the answer to include that. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks guys, it works if I manually enter the url but if I link it to html <a> tag it won't work :/   `<a href="<?php get_site_url() . '/?my_plugin_show_phpinfo=1' ?>" target="_blank">Click to view your system's configuration in a new window</a>`   outputting the get_site_url() . '/?my_plugin_show_phpinfo=1 with `var_dump`

Comment: @KristenSepp `get_site_url()` needs to be printed: `<?php echo get_site_url() . '/?my_plugin_show_phpinfo=1' ?>`